# Excel check the form/mask of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a huge spreadsheet with thousands of values on column A.

The values have the form/mask of xxx-xx.xx or xx-xxx.xxx

I need to check what form/mask each value has and return the mask to column B.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I can find any excel function for this. If excel can't help, maybe there is a vba function for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

1. the values are **Text** values
2. the data is in column **A**

In **B1** enter:

```
=FIND("-",A1)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

The value in column **B** indicates which of two formats is in a column **A** cell.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "like"
the wild cards are:
? any single character

## any single numeric character

- 0 to many characters
  [ABC] any of the characters in the list between [ and ], in this case A, B or C
  [!ABC] not any of the characters in the list between [ and ]
  All other values will be the value they are.

if wValue like "???-??.??" then
a=1
elseif wValue like "??-???.???"
a=2
else
a=0
end if

if you want to check for a ? in a specific position (e.g. 4) you can use "???[?]*"
three characters followed by the question mark followed by any number of characters

"-" anywhere in the string "*-*"
"-" anywhere in the string except as the first or last character - "[!-]*-*[!-]"